# How to check if a sequence is increasing with +1 increment clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am making poker game in clojure I have a function like:

```
(sort (map rank straight-hand))
```

that returns rank of the hand in sort order let say

```
(2 3 4 5 6)
```

how to check that the difference of preceding number and current number in the sequence is 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(every? #{1} (map - (rest hand) hand))
```

This verifies that every result of subtracting an item from the following in your hand is in the set `#{1}`

Comment: `(apply = 1 (map - (rest hand) hand))`

Answer (score 3):

Use `(partition 2 1 <seq>)` to break your sorted sequence into overlapping groups of two, then get the difference of each group of two, then test that each difference is -1:

```
(defn incrementing?
  [xs]
  (every? #(= % -1) (map #(apply - %) (partition 2 1 xs))))
```

Comment: or `(every? (fn [[x y]] (= y (inc x))) (partition 2 1 '(2 3 4 5 6)))`

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way: you want to check that what you have is a range. So compare it to the range between the first and the last element of your list.

```
  (= xs (range (first xs)
           (inc (last xs))))
```

Comment: +1 - interesting solution. Note, however, that this breaks if `xs` is not monotonically increasing, e.g. if `(def xs '(1 2 3 4 6 5))`.

Comment: @BobJarvis the problem statement stated that the input was sorted

Comment: If the input wasn't sorted, you could compare the set of xs with the set of the range between the min and max of xs.